# How to pass a location parameter in when calculating distance?

Tags: database, go, geospatial, crate, cratedb

I would like to execute the following query from my Go application

```
SELECT hour, count 
FROM location_counts 
WHERE distance(point, 'POINT(-80.205 26.14)') <= 100
```

I will be passing in the `POINT(-80.205 26.14)` and `100` values and I'm not quite sure how to include the `POINT...` parameter in a secure way.  When I try to pass it in as a parameter like below:

```
rows, err := g.DB.Query(
    "select hour, count from location_counts where distance(point, '?') <= ?",
    "POINT(-80.205 26.14)",
    100,
)
```

It throws the error:

> SQLActionException[SQLParseException: Cannot cast 'POINT(-80.205
>   26.14)' to type double]

If I drop the value directly into the string it works but I would open myself up for SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

How can I securely include the `POINT...` value in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the surrounding quotes of the placeholder question mark should fix it, like:

`rows, err := g.DB.Query(
    "select hour, count from location_counts where distance(point, ?) <= ?",
    "POINT(-80.205 26.14)",
    100,
)`

Placeholders should never be quoted as they will be replaced directly by the typed parameter.